# Where can I store code for Events? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, controls

I'm a relatively new programmer, using VB.NET 2017.

I'm making a business application which stores a user's information, for them to then log in with, and allow them to purchase products or book services.

A lot of my controls have some random events tied to them (like an image having a "MouseHover" event), and they're really building up and making the code look unorganised: [Chunk of event stuff.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EQJl.png) Can I throw these chunks of code into a storage place somewhere away from my main code?

Comment: what does this mean? ... `throw these chunks of code`

Comment: Well, you might actually have it around the wrong way.  Generally you would separate out the bulk of your main code to things like classes and/or modules etc for re-usability.  The screenshot you've added looks pretty norm to me.  Or you could use something #Region #End Region to wrap your even handlers and collapse it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes you can. Have a look at [event handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/) and [AddHandler statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-call-an-event-handler). But as of now, judging from the pic you posted, your code looks as tidy as it can get. Any (control) event handler should have as few lines of code as possible, with the actual processing done in separate objects called by the event.

Comment: @Hursey Thank you for your reply. I think I see what you mean. Right now I have been creating separate procedures full of code at the bottom of the program and then calling them into the Subs that the event creates: [Example](https://imgur.com/a/RNAU4yU). Are you saying I could put these procedures into a Module/Class and call them from there, and then leave all of the "Miscellaneous" events like Button.MouseHover in the main code of the form?

(Thank you to all of the replies so far)

Comment: Well really it all comes down to personal style and your preferences so pretty subjective.  I myself try to divide UI and business logic into separate projects.  In effect all I do in my UI is have any code that is specifically to format user output and event handlers that call methods in my business logic code.

Comment: There are many different ways to organise your code, but the one key thing I will tell everyone is use clear naming of variables, objects, controls and methods.  That alone will make your code much more manageable.  All that aside though, being such a subjective topic, this really is all a bit off topic for this forum.